# Using openpyxl and scipy to solve non-linear system related to resistor network

Tags: numpy, scipy, openpyxl, fsolve

I'm trying to do the right thing for my career by learning how to really use the data science tools and automate excel.

There is a pretty basic resistor circuit called a Pi attenuator.
On a particular component, two of the terminals are shorted together by design.
Because these two of the elements are common (Terminal 3 shorts R1 and R2 - see spreadsheet screenshot) it isn't possible to just measure them with a meter and get the real value of the element. What is measured

I have measurement data both before and after exposing them to high temp oven

[image]

The left side has the Before oven measurements (measured and converted)

I was able to use scipy fsolve to get the correct element values (as if R1 and R2 weren't common). This code absolutely works and gives the correct info.
[image]

The F[] equations came from solving for the series/parallel value when an ohmmeter is put across pins (1,3), (2,3), and (1,2). I know those are correct. As I understand it, the system is non-linear because of the variables existing in the denominators.

[image]

I used this function to manually enter the starting measurements and converted them to their real values.

The problem is that I need to do this hundreds of times for many test groups, and will need to test other attenuator values. I don't want to have to re-run the script after tying in successive measurements if I can help it.

I'm able to get the data out of excel and into numpy arrays, but when I pass the data to the fsolve function I get
printed values of that have add a bunch of decimal places
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars-divide by zero encountered in double_scalars

[image]

To me these are scary insurmountable issues. The lines the warnings occurred on might have changed, but they happen during the F[] = equation assignments.

I wanted to be able to provide the spreadsheet but I'm told this link won't work.
[Actual excel datafile](https://murena.io/s/Ap6kkBPpTjWtQmk)

The code I'm working with that uses openpyxl has been limited to 1 row of data for my sanity. If I can get the correct values I would tackle the next part next.

I tried to do what I could to lay out the basis of what I'm doing with screenshots and by providing as much detail as possible. I'm hoping to receive feedback about how to do what I've explained by using numpy arrays, fsolve, and openpyxl.

In general (in my personal programming "experience") I have issues with making sure I've casted to the correct type. I wouldn't be surprised if that was part of my problem. I have issues with "scope". I also overthink everything, and the majority of my EE schooling used C or assembly.

It's embarrassing to say how long it too me to even get this far. I'm so ignorant that I don't even know what I don't know. I've put it down and picked it back up enough that I'm starting to get emotional and need another set of eyes. I'm trying to fail forward here, but I need another set of eyes.

I tried:
-enforcing float64 (or float32) dtype to the np arrays
-creating other np arrays in the convert_measured function
-casting the parameters passed to convert_measured to seperate variables within the function
-rounding the values from the cells because they seem to expand. I don't need any more than 2 decimals of precision for this

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("datafile.xlsx")
ws = wb['Group A']

""" Excel Data Cell Locations
Measured R1,R2,R3 Effective Starting Values
Group A,B,C,D worksheet -Cell Range I15 to K34
I = column 9
K = colum 11
"""
#Data limited to just one row here to debug 
MeasColBegin = int(9)
MeasColEnd = int(11) 
MeasRowBegin = int(15) # Measured values start in row 15
MeasRowEnd = int(15) # Row 34 is the real end. If this is set to 15 then it's only looking at one row

rows_input = ws.iter_rows(min_row=MeasRowBegin,max_row=MeasRowEnd, min_col=MeasColBegin,max_col=MeasColEnd)

"""
Calculated R1,R2,R3 Actual Finished Values 
Group A,B,C,D worksheet -Cell Range I39 to K58
I = column 9
K = colum 11
"""
#These aren't being used yet
CalcColBegin = int(9)
CalcColEnd = int(11)
CalcRowBegin = int(39)
CalcRowEnd = int(58)

#row iterator for actual/calculated values
#This isn't being used yet later
rows_output = ws.iter_rows(min_row=CalcRowBegin,max_row=CalcRowEnd, min_col=CalcColBegin,max_col=CalcColEnd)

#This is called by fsolve
#This works when I don't use data passed from the excel spreadsheet
def convert_measured(z): #Maybe I need to cast z to a different type/size...?
   F = np.empty((3))
   F.astype('float64')
   #print("z datatypes ", z[0].dtype, z[1].dtype, z[2].dtype)

   # IDK why this prints so many decimal places, (or why it prints them so many times)
   # I assume it has to do how the optimizer works
   #print("z[]= ", z[0], z[1], z[2]) 
   
   # Same assignments as simplier version of code that provides correct answers
   #x = z[0]
   #y = z[1]
   #w = z[2]
   x = z[0]
   y = z[1]
   w = z[2]
   #print("x=",x," y=",y," w=",w)

   #This is certainly wrong
   F[0] = 1/(1/z[0]+1/(z[1]+z[2]))-z[0]
   F[1] = 1/(1/z[1]+1/(z[0]+z[2]))-z[1]
   F[2] = 1/(1/z[2]+1/(z[0]+z[1]))-z[2]

   #I tried thinking that rounding might help. Nope.
   #F[0] = 1/(1/x+1/(y+w))-np.around(z[0],4)
   #F[1] = 1/(1/y+1/(x+w))-np.around(z[1],4)
   #F[2] = 1/(1/w+1/(x+y))-np.around(z[2],4)


   #Original code from example that works when I enter the numbers
   #F[0] = 1/(1/x+1/(y+w))-148.884
   #F[1] = 1/(1/y+1/(x+w))-148.853
   #F[2] = 1/(1/w+1/(x+y))-16.506
   #Bottom line is that one of my problems is that I don't know how to represet F[0,1,2] in terms of z
   return F

def main():
   # numpy array where measured values to be converted will go
   zGuess = np.array([1,1,1])
   zGuess = zGuess.astype('float64')

   # numpy array where converted solution/values will go
   zSol = np.array([1,1,1])
   zSol = zSol.astype('float64')

   # For loop used to iterate through rows and extract measurements
   # These are passed to the convert_measured function
   for row in rows_input:
      print("row[]= ", row[0].value, row[1].value, row[2].value) #print out values to check it's the right data
      #store values into np array that will be sent to convert_measured
      zGuess[0]=row[0].value
      zGuess[1]=row[1].value
      zGuess[2]=row[2].value
      print("zGuess[]=", zGuess[0], zGuess[1], zGuess[2]) #print again to make sure because I had problems with dtype

      # Solve for measurements / Convert to actual values
      zSol = fsolve(convert_measured, zGuess)
      
      #This should print the true values of the elements as if no shunt between R1 and R2 exists
      print("zSol= ",zSol[0], zSol[1], zSol[2]) 

      #Todo: store correct solutions into array and write to spreadsheet


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This should be more readable now.

Comment: For whatever reason, the excel link actually did work - the other ones required authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some changes to your code and ran this on your manually calculated data. The result looks to be the same apart from a few rounding differences.
Therefore 'rows_input' currently points to the range C15:E34 in the code sample (other rows_input line is commented out).
The main change was to the line that calls the convert function

```
zSol = fsolve(convert_measured, zGuess)
```

to call the function with the params for calculating and round the array values to 2 decimal places

```
zSol = np.round(fsolve(convert_measured, zSol, zGuess), 2)
```

The convert_measured function was also changed to accept the inputs for the conversions.

Changed code sample below; (I commented out the print statements except for the zsol values)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("datafile.xlsx")
ws = wb['Group A']

""" Excel Data Cell Locations
Measured R1,R2,R3 Effective Starting Values
Group A,B,C,D worksheet -Cell Range I15 to K34
I = column 9
K = colum 11
"""
# Data limited to just one row here to debug
MeasColBegin = int(9)
MeasColEnd = int(11)
MeasRowBegin = int(15)  # Measured values start in row 15
MeasRowEnd = int(15)  # Row 34 is the real end. If this is set to 15 then it's only looking at one row

# rows_input = ws.iter_rows(min_row=MeasRowBegin, max_row=MeasRowEnd, min_col=MeasColBegin, max_col=MeasColEnd)
rows_input = ws.iter_rows(min_row=15, max_row=34, min_col=3, max_col=5)

"""
Calculated R1,R2,R3 Actual Finished Values 
Group A,B,C,D worksheet -Cell Range I39 to K58
I = column 9
K = colum 11
"""
# These aren't being used yet
CalcColBegin = int(9)
CalcColEnd = int(11)
CalcRowBegin = int(39)
CalcRowEnd = int(58)

# row iterator for actual/calculated values
# This isn't being used yet later
rows_output = ws.iter_rows(min_row=CalcRowBegin, max_row=CalcRowEnd, min_col=CalcColBegin, max_col=CalcColEnd)

def convert_measured(z, xl):
    F = np.empty((3))
    # F.astype('float64')

    x = z[0]
    y = z[1]
    w = z[2]

    # Original code from example that works when I enter the numbers
    F[0] = 1/(1/x+1/(y+w))-xl[0]
    F[1] = 1/(1/y+1/(x+w))-xl[1]
    F[2] = 1/(1/w+1/(x+y))-xl[2]

    return F


def main():
    # numpy array where measured values to be converted will go
    zGuess = np.array([1, 1, 1])
    zGuess = zGuess.astype('float64')

    # numpy array where converted solution/values will go
    zSol = np.array([1, 1, 1])
    zSol = zSol.astype('float64')

    # For loop used to iterate through rows and extract measurements
    # These are passed to the convert_measured function
    for row in rows_input:
        #print("row[]= ", row[0].value, row[1].value, row[2].value)  # print out values to check it's the right data
        # store values into np array that will be sent to convert_measured
        zGuess[0] = row[0].value
        zGuess[1] = row[1].value
        zGuess[2] = row[2].value
        #print("zGuess[]=", zGuess[0], zGuess[1], zGuess[2])  # print again to make sure because I had problems with dtype

        # Solve for measurements / Convert to actual values
        # zSol = fsolve(convert_measured(zSol), zGuess)
        zSol = np.round(fsolve(convert_measured, zSol, zGuess), 2)

        # This should print the true values of the elements as if no shunt between R1 and R2 exists
        print("zSol= ", zSol[0], zSol[1], zSol[2])

        # Todo: store correct solutions into array and write to spreadsheet


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output looks like this

```
zSol=  290.03 288.94 16.99
zSol=  283.68 294.84 16.97
zSol=  280.83 297.43 17.07
zSol=  292.67 286.63 16.99
zSol=  277.51 301.04 16.93
zSol=  294.98 284.66 16.95
...
```

Comment: Thank you so very much moken. You made my week and I'm very grateful.